# How to check User login history on a Windows 11 machine (without third parrty tools)

Tags: windows, user-accounts, login

I was following this tut: https://ourtechroom.com/fix/how-to-find-or-check-windows-10-user-login-history/ suggesting that Event Viewer tool might help discover user login history, but when i apply to my machine i find many login events (many ID 4624 events) that are not consistent with my login history on my computer.

How to properly check history of user login on WIndows 11?

THanks

Comment: Successful logons by local users aren't logged by default IIRC. It has to be enabled in the policy editor if regular logons should show up. SYSTEM, User and Network accounts all have different policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable the audit of logon events :

- Run the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Position to :
  *Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy*
- Double-click "Audit logon events"
- Check both "Success" and "Failure"
- Click Apply
- Click OK.

After these steps, Windows will track login attempts, both successful
or failed.

To check who logged into your computer, in the Event Viewer,
section *Windows Logs > Security*, find all occurrences of event ID `4624`.

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to Check Computer Login History on Windows 10/11?](https://www.minitool.com/news/how-to-check-computer-login-history-windows-10-11.html)

Comment: OK thanks, also when i right click on a software icon and in General tab try to check the last accessed time property, it says 1 min ago, so it doesn't show the last access time. How to get the last access for a software?

Comment: No right-click needed. This might help : [How to work with custom views in Event Viewer (all Windows versions)](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-work-custom-views-event-viewer/).

Comment: How to get the last accessed property on a folder easily?

Comment: using this https://smallbusiness.chron.com/check-program-last-used-72626.html it only gets me the current right click access not the "last" access time to the software

Comment: Your question was about logon history. Program usage is a very different question.

Comment: check my new question about that (that was closed for no reason)

Comment: If you want that other question to be reopened you should: 1) Do what the moderator of this site (DavidPostill) asked you to do, 2) Explain there what you do without using a link so your question becomes self-contained. I can't intercede on that question as long as it's closed since I'm not a moderator.

Comment: i am not here to help you organize your platform, i am simply here to ask a question